# Aggregate nested array element

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have troubles with aggregations. I have collection "stations" with theese fiels:

```
stationName: string,
systemName: string,
commodities:[{
    name: string,
    buyPrice: number,
    sellPrice: number,
    stock: number,
    demand: number
}]
```

I need to query max and min price for specific commodity. For example: I have commodity "water" and need to get highest sellPrice at all stations entries.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.stations.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$commodities"},
    { $match: { "commodities.name":"clothing" }}, //clothing as example
    { $sort: { "commodities.buyPrice":-1 }},
    { $limit: 10}
])
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing an `aggregate` query with `$max`/`$min`,

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      stationName: true,
      systemName: true,
      maxBuyPrice: {
        $max: "$commodities.buyPrice"
      },
      maxSellPrice: {
        $max: "$commodities.sellPrice"
      },
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z-TjrEgKtrO).

For the min price you can replace `$max` with `$min` in the query, or include both if that's what you want

Comment: Thanks, but I also need aggregation by commodity name. I guess it shoud be  ```$eq: ["$commodities.name", "water"] ``` but this not works